# How to manipulate elements inside ng-if without using a directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I´m having issues trying to execute DOM manipulation sentences for elements inside a ng-if.

I think the problem here is that DOM is not ready when manipulation code runs.

There is a way to do this without a directive?

Example(two select one inside ng-if handle by a checkbox):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Select2 Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./bower_components/select2/dist/css/select2.css">
</head>
<body ng-app="Myapp">
    <div class="container" ng-controller="Select2Controller">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <select id="myselect" style="width:200px;">
                    <option value="1">option1</option>
                    <option value="2">option2</option>
                    <option value="3">option3</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <input type="checkbox" name="toogle" ng-model="checked">Show ng-if nested select</input>
                <div ng-if="checked">
                    <select id="myselect2" style="width:200px;">
                    <option value="4">option4</option>
                    <option value="5">option5</option>
                    <option value="6">option6</option>
                </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="./bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js" ></script>
    <script src="./bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js" ></script>
    <script src="./bower_components/angular/angular.js" ></script>
    <script src="./select.ctrl.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="./app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller:

```
var app = angular.module("Myapp", []);

app.controller("Select2Controller", function($scope) {

    $scope.checked = false;   

   $( document ).ready(function() {
        //This code works 
        $("#myselect").append("<option value='4'>new option</option>");
    });

    $scope.$watch('checked', function (newVal, oldVal) {
        if (newVal && $scope.checked) {
            $(document).ready(function () {
                //Not works
                $("#myselect2").append("<option value='7'>new option</option>");
            });  
        }
    });

});
```

First select behaves well but the second select remains equal, no option added in this case.

I tried other sentences and happens the same history. ng-show works because of its nature(The hidden elements are there to be manipulated) but it does not fit my needs.

I´m searching for a general answer, add and option is just an example. The sentence could be anything that manipulates the nested ng-if elements.

Any idea or solution? thanks

Comment: @ieaglle I´m not asking for design and the code is just for testing/showing the problem. The setTimeout function smells like bad design too. Thanks for your answer and tips.

Comment: What exactly is the question? I gave you 3 answers and all of them do exactly what you want to achieve but none of them is "the right answer". I'd do the whole select with either https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select or https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat. I don't even understand why do you want to append an option for a select which isn't even visible. Why can't the "new option" be in the select already, since the whole select isn't visible? I'd understand if you have checkbox to toggle select visibility and another checkbox/select which adds/removes options.

Comment: @Kirbo I said that adding an element to the select it´s just an example. Could be another kind of tag and other task to be done. SetTimeout it´s a dirty way to handle stuff like that. Directives are probably the mandatory way to deal with DOM manipulation in AngularJS. The best comment/answer is Ethnar´s one. I really appreciate your  effort. I think that my question has a bad start point.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use `ng-if` for the option? Like:

```
<div ng-if="checked">
    <select id="myselect2" style="width:200px;">
        <option value="4">option4</option>
        <option value="5">option5</option>
        <option value="6">option6</option>
        <option ng-if="something" value="7">option7</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: I´m searching for a general answer, add and option is just an example.

Comment: This answer raises a very good point. If you're doing things the angular way - why mixing it with JS/jQuery, especially on application controller level?
Generally speaking it's much better to rely and work angular way all the way rather than just using some pieces, part of the reason for this is the  issue you encounter with your code posted here

Comment: @Ethnar Great comment but does not answer how solve this "non-angular way". I don´t believe it is impossible. Simply curiosity.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-repeat`:

Controller:

```
$scope.select = [
    {value: 4, label: 'option 4'},
    {value: 5, label: 'option 5'},
    {value: 6, label: 'option 6'},
];
```

View:

```
<div ng-if="checked">
    <select ng-model="select">
        <option value="option.value" ng-repeat="option in select">{{ option.label }}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Then your select is dynamic. Later when you want to add more options, just use `$scope.select.push({value: 7, label: 'option 7'});` etc

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing this:

```
$scope.$watch('checked', function (newVal, oldVal) {
    if (newVal && $scope.checked) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            //Not works
            $("#myselect2").append("<option value='7'>new option</option>");
        });  
    }
});
```

Into this:

```
$scope.$watch('checked', function (newVal, oldVal) {
    if (newVal && $scope.checked) {
        $timeout(function(){
            $("#myselect2").append("<option value='7'>new option</option>");
        });  
    }
});
```

More info of `$timeout` can be found in: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout

Comment: Yes it solves the problem but is the same that say "wait enough time to DOM to be ready" not saying when elements are ready -> run the code.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that by "without a directive" you mean without a *custom* directive.

You can bind the select options to an array on the scope using the ngOptions directive:

HTML:

```
<select id="myselect2" ng-model="selectedOption" ng-options="option for option in options"></select>
```

Controller:

```
app.controller("Select2Controller", function($scope) {

  $scope.checked = false;
  $scope.options = ['option1', 'option2'];

  $scope.$watch('checked', function (newVal, oldVal) {
    if (newVal) {
      $scope.options.push('option3');  
    } else {
      $scope.options.pop();
    }
  });
});
```